# How to skip the start and end lines from a CSV with Apache Beam Python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to skip the initial and final lines of a CSV with **Apache Beam Python**. For the initial lines I could use `apache_beam.io.ReadFromText('example.csv', skip_header_lines=10)` but also I need remove the X ending lines. Reading `apache_beam.dataframe.io.read_csv` I found this parameter:

> **skipfooter** (int, default 0) – Number of lines at bottom of file to skip (Unsupported with engine=’c’).

So I have this code:

```py
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
    beam_df = p | beam.dataframe.io.read_csv('example.csv', engine='python', header=None,
                                             skiprows=10, skipfooter=15)
```

But this exception is thrown: `ValueError: 'skipfooter' not supported for iteration`

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.